# Java utils binary search not finding all values

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to search an array for a value and decided to use the built in binary search to do so. I have a class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Charge {
private int isAcct;
private int[] acctNumbers = {5658845,4520125,7895122,8777541,8451277,
1302850,8080152,4562555,5552012,5050552,7824577,
                    1250255,1005231,6545231,3852085,7576651,7881200,
                    4851002};


public Charge(int aNum) {
    isAcct = aNum;
}
public Boolean isValidAcctNumber() {
    int m = Arrays.binarySearch(acctNumbers, isAcct);
    if (m == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

And a test:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChargeTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your account number?: ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    Charge charge = new Charge(num);
    System.out.println(charge.isValidAcctNumber());

    if (charge.isValidAcctNumber() == false) {
        System.out.println("Your account "+num+" is not a valid account");
    } else  {
        System.out.println("Your account "+num+" is a valid account");
    }
}
```

}

This works for certain numbers like 4851002, but not others like 1302850. I really haven't the foggiest idea why. I will most likely just implement binary search by hand, but I am confused as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: You really should read at least part of the docs for binary search before asking a question.

Comment: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) clearly states: **The array must be sorted**. If parts of the JDK misbehave, read it's docs before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary search only works on an array that [is already sorted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29).

Quoted from `Arrays.binarySearch` javadoc:

> Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the
>   binary search algorithm. The array must be sorted (as by the
>   sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted,
>   the results are undefined. If the array contains multiple elements
>   with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be
>   found.

If it's not already sorted, then it will not find some numbers.

[Sort it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29) before attempting any binary search:

```
Arrays.sort(acctNumbers);
```

Comment: +1 for a fuller answer than mine, and to make up for the troll who downvoted the correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

A binary search requires a sorted array.

You could:

- Provide the array in sorted order
- Or sort it with [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)

Comment: +1 to make up for the downvoter who downvoted a correct answer and for suggesting to simply provide the array already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If Java used chaining it would look like

```
if ( Arrays.sort(acctNumbers).find( number ) )
```

Now you have to do

```
List l = Arrays.sort(acctNumbers);
// decide on 
Arrays.binarySearch( l, number );
```